# How to add DotNetBar form in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to edit an old project of mine (made with VS2010 Express). There I could add DotNetBar forms easily, but now when I open my project with VS2012 I have no option to add a DotNetBar form anymore.

I tried deleting and then re-adding the referrence but nothing changed. How can I do this?

Comment: Try right clicking on your Toolbox and select Choose Items, then browse to where the DLl/Ocx is located and select it. It should then add it to your Toolbox.

Comment: I know about that, but I need to know how to add DotNetBar forms in that Add Item (Add Windows Form) menu.